# Does importing from @ag-grid-community/core and @ag-grid-enterprise/core increase bundle size?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

In Typescript, some type definitions seem only to be exported in `@ag-grid-community/core` and does not exist in `@ag-grid-enterprise`.

In this case, I am having to use both modules, and wonder if this is increasing the bundle size by having duplicate code across the two modules? I only require some type definitions at this point, and will need to use enterprise version in production.

Comment: `@ag-grid-community/core` and `@ag-grid-enterprise/core` don't contain duplicate code. For most projects you don't need to worry about bundle size, other than only importing the modules you actually need: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/